# Is there any closed form solution available for the following equation

Tags: roots, lambert-w

I have to find the solution for following equation $$e^{ax^2+ax}=(1+ax)^{ax+1}$$ where $a\geq 0$. I can solve it for $a=1$ but I do not know how to solve it for general values of $a$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: What's a nontrivial solution when $a=1$?

Comment: @Jeff using Lambert W function we can find the solution

Comment: @FrankMoses: how? To eliminate the quadratic term does not look trivial to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think quadratic term will vanish by putting $a=1$.

Comment: @FrankMoses: all right, I thought the statement *using Lambert W function we can find the solution* was about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

$x=0$ is a solution for any $a$.  This is not the only solution in $\mathbb C$, but I suspect it may be the only solution in $\mathbb R$ if $a > 0$.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning it in the question but I am interested in non-zero solution.

Answer (score 0):

By letting $ax=z$ and switching to logarithms the problem boils down to finding a positive solution of

$$ \frac{1}{a}=\frac{(1+z)\log(1+z)-z}{z^2} $$
which exists for any $a>2$ and can be found by Newton's method: the RHS is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ which approximately behaves like $\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7 z}{30}}{1+\frac{4 z}{5}+\frac{z^2}{10}}$ (this is a Padé approximant at the origin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think that the answer can be formulated as a close form expression?